# How does Maven only package referenced classes?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven 3.

2 modules: M1 and M2

There is a class in M2 named B.class which will reference A.class, A.class is in the first module M1. M1 has many classes, such as 100 classes as example.

When I execute command under M2, is it possible **only** package **B.class and A.class** to the jar **rather than** B.class and all classes in M1 ?

```
mvn clean package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven shade plugin can build minimised jars only containing the classes you use.

Comment: should I exclude the classes in the config file ? could it exclude all the non-referenced classes automatically ?

Comment: `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` should be enough to do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I looking for several days~!!